# UIPopover Delegate - Unable to assign regardless of protocal/declarations

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, delegates, uipopovercontroller

I'm having some difficulty figure out what I'm doing wrong when trying to assign my a delegate for my UIPopoverView. I tried to work around not even using one, but having it would be much more straightforward and clean. Here is the code that I think should cover it:

```
//.h of View where I call popover, this would be the delegate.

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ACTypePopoverViewController.h"

@interface NewRouteViewController : UIViewController<ACTypePickerDelegate>{

    ACTypePopoverViewController *_acTypePicker;
    UIPopoverController *_acTypePickerPopover;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) ACTypePopoverViewController *acTypePicker;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIPopoverController *acTypePickerPopover;

@end

//.m file for where I would like to use the popover, is the .m for the .h above

if (_acTypePickerPopover == nil)
{
    ACTypePopoverViewController* content = [[ACTypePopoverViewController alloc] init];
    UIPopoverController* aPopover = [[UIPopoverController alloc]
                                 initWithContentViewController:content];
    aPopover.delegate = self;
    [content release];

    // Store the popover in a custom property for later use.
    self.acTypePickerPopover = aPopover;
}   

[self.acTypePickerPopover presentPopoverFromRect:self.selectACTypeButton.frame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionLeft animated:YES];

//.h file for the actual popover, what I would be setting the delegate of

@protocol ACTypePickerDelegate
- (void)acTypeSelected:(NSString *)acType;
@end

@interface ACTypePopoverViewController : UITableViewController {
    NSMutableArray *_acTypes;
    NSString *selectedACType;
    id<ACTypePickerDelegate> _delegate;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *acTypes;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *selectedACType;
@property (nonatomic, assign) id<ACTypePickerDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

I think thats all I need, but let me know if more code is needed!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understood you correctly... what you need is:

```
content.delegate = self;
```

Right after this line you have:

```
ACTypePopoverViewController* content = [[ACTypePopoverViewController alloc] init];
```

Comment: That makes a whole lot of sense, and of course it works now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you synthesizing your properties? Also you are assigning your delegate before initiating the popover...

`@synthesize acTypePickerPopover;`
`self.acTypePickerPopover = [[[UIPopoverController alloc] 
                                initWithContentViewController:_acTypePickerPopover] autorelease];`
`self.acTypePickerPopover.delegate = self;`
`

Comment: Oops! I was playing around with it and I think I messed that up at a later point. I stepped through with the debugger, and when I actually assign the delegate the value is correct, but when I go to access the delegate from the popover it no longer has a value, any ideas on why?

Comment: You said you are trying to access the delegate from the popover. How are you doing that? You will not be able to access it from your UITableViewController -- the UITableViewController is within the UIPopOverController, they are not the same thing. Is this what you are trying to do?